# Perform a scroll and find an element by accessibility id - webdriverio with Appium

Tags: webdriver-io, appium-android

I will greatly appreciate if someone can help me with this. I am new to automation testing and I am using webdriverio and Appium. The test I want to write(native app) is the following:

1. Vertically scroll down to an element
2. Locate the element by accessibility id
3. Click on the element

The element only has accessibility id. I don't know how to locate it using accessibility id.

The question is how to write the test to scroll down to the particular element, locate it by its accessibility id and click on it.

I tried to use UiScrollable class and wrote this:

```
it('Scroll down to and click on wellness category', async () => {
    await $('android=new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).flingToEnd(1)');
    const wellness = await $('~wellness');
    await wellness.click();
    await driver.pause(1000);
});
```

This scrolls down to the end of the screen but it cannot locate the element.

These are the capabilities:
capabilities: [
{
"appium:platformName": "Android",
"appium:platformVersion": "11.0",
"appium:deviceName": "Pixel 4a API 30",
"appium:automationName": "UIAutomator2",
"appium:app": path.join(process.cwd(), "path to the apk"),
"appium:autoGrantPermissions": true
},

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved this:

```
//Android scroll forward and backward
async swipeForward()
  {
      await driver.pause(2000)
      await $('android=new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollForward()');
  }

  // Swipe backward
  async swipeBackward()
  {
      await driver.pause(2000)
      await $('android=new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollBackward()');
  }
```

This is what I wrote and I was able to scroll to the element, identify it by id and click on it:

```
it('Click on wellness category', async () => {
        await $('android=new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollForward()');
        const wellness = await $('~accessibility id here');
        await wellness.click();
        await driver.pause(2000);
    });
```